# Confirmation review (upgrade from MPhil to PhD) chair can ask a lot of questions

Tags: phd, thesis-committee

Recently a friend o mine has her update meeting and there were two examiners and a chair.  Chair has asked much more questions than the examiners and he put her in a hard situation and eventually the examiners decided to fail her based on the chair comments.

Does really a chair there to ask questions or just modareta the meeting? My friend wants to  make an objection to their decision mainly because of the chair approach and role.

Does it make sense?

Comment: Which country is that?

Comment: Seems the chair has a bad impression on your friend. Did your friend perform well enough in the examination? Whether the chair asked many questions outside of your friend's research interest?

Comment: Can you help me understand how the chair was chosen?  I would have thought the chair would be your advisor, who would normally not allow the student to schedule such an exam prematurely.  My reaction to your question is, With a "friend" like this, who needs enemies?

Comment: It is UK @CaptainEmacs.

Comment: She has failed unfortunately. I have read their feedback, none of them reflect the questions asked during the meeting. What they claimed is, she is not ready for PhD, and she has not developed her enough. The feedback are too subjective. I advised her to seek for appeal and take legal actions.... Thank you for comments and replies.

Comment: The chair can ask questions. The issue is: can the case be made that the chair asked questions specifically designed to fail her (e.g. in the sense that they were not contributing to clarifying the candidate's mastery of her material to be worthy of a PhD)? The upgrade from MPhil to PhD sounds strange. Often in the UK an MPhil is an indication of work that is "not quite" up to the standards of a PhD, but did not fail outright to contribute any scientific value. So, the upgrade might be an attempt to argue the other way round? - if so, reversing a previous verdict is a tougher call to make.

Answer (score 1):

The point is: Who asks the questions really makes no difference if your friend doesn't know the answers.

You seem to make the inference that the process was unfair because the wrong person asked the questions. But that's the wrong attitude. The process would have been unfair if your friend had been well prepared, had known the answers, and was rejected nonetheless.

Let's assume the chair had only taken the role of the moderator. Then there are two outcomes: (i) The other members had asked more questions and would also have found out that your friend did not know the answers; in that case, they would probably have come to the same conclusion. (ii) The other members had not asked questions, it would not have been as apparent that your friend did not know the answers, they may have admitted your friend to the PhD program, and she would struggled a lot because she is not well prepared.

Comment: Thank you @Wolfgang.Who asked questions is matter. The chair was also a postgraduate officer and she was not happy with my friend for not attending the postgraduate meetings (attendance is not a compulsory but advised). The chair has asked her about meetings first he could not use these reason in the report, therefore he exaggerated the questions. Even the best students can miss some questions. Eventually, in the feedback report, he did not mention any question asked during the meeting. The failure explained with vague and subjective claims. Thats why I advised my friend to take legal actions.

Comment: Look, you're as prejudices against the chair as you claim he is against your friend. There were two other professors in the room who signed the form that she failed. They must have seen the same thing -- or they would not have voted that way. I know you claim that they voted on his recommendation, but professors are a notoriously independent bunch: they're not going to vote for anything unless they're convinced it's the right thing to do. What you're saying is that all three of them are in the wrong; that may be correct, but it seems statistically unlikely.